# PHP PDO Microsoft SQL

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

However im trying to grab the 5 last entrys in a db and echo their first row out on the site, this is how far I've gotten:

```
<?php

$dsn = "sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=blog";
$conn = new PDO($dsn, "*****", "*********");
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$sql = "SELECT TOP 5 FROM blog_posts ORDER BY blogID DESC";

foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
echo $row[1];
} 
?>
```

error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.' in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev\ny\includes\left-menu.php:17 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev\ny\includes\left-menu.php(17):
>   PDO->query('SELECT TOP 5 FR...') #1
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev\ny\index.php(281):
>   include('C:\inetpub\wwwr...') #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dev\ny\includes\left-menu.php on line 17

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Mureinik it does not echo anything atm

Comment: managed to solve it.... missing a * after TOP 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The row

```
$sql = "SELECT TOP 5 FROM blog_posts ORDER BY blogID DESC";
```

should have been

```
$sql = "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM blog_posts ORDER BY blogID DESC";
```

Comment: Does this entirely fix the issue? Shouldn't you fetch the result? Your `foreach` loops [sqlserv_query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296184(v=sql.105).aspx) value, the statement result that returns `false` if fails.

Comment: @parfait yes it doesnt return any errors and works as i wanted :)